# Why is textbox.focus throwing the lostfocus event?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I've seen a few similar questions on SO but nothing that seems to actually address the issue. Here's a simplified version of the function.

```
Private Sub Check_Quantity(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) _
    Handles textbox_quantity.LostFocus

        Dim worked As Boolean = Integer.TryParse(textbox_quantity.Text, quantity)

        If Not worked Then
            MsgBox("Enter a valid number for the quantity")
            textbox_quantity.Focus()
            textbox_quantity.SelectAll()
            quantity = 0
        End If
End Sub
```

It's important to note that this is WPF. What I want to do is very simple. When someone finishes with the textbox the program checks that what they entered is a number. If it does it sticks this in an integer. If not, it tells them to fix it and keeps the focus on the textbox. The issue is a few things, but what it comes down to is this function runs in an infinite loop. This same function works fine in WinForms, but not in WPF.

On some other questions people have said that the messagebox appearing causes focus to be lost, but in testing this isn't true. It still loops regardless of if the messagebox is called or not. The problem is the call to textbox_quantity.Focus(). Without that it works fine. Regardless of whether it's there or not though, focus is not set to the textbox, though textbox_quantity.Focus() still returns a value of true. Any thought of what's going on and maybe how I could fix it?

Comment: @HansPassant What? It isn't a function and it isn't called by other code of mine, it's called from an event (Note the "Handles textbox_quantity.LostFocus"). It doesn't return anything nor does it need to. I was referring to the line of code textbox_quantity.Focus() returning a value of true when I check the return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that focus() is executed exactly when you call it... so just before the focus is given to the other control... Hence the loop... A workaround i've found is to postpone the execution of such code using System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem. But since focus() must be called from the window thread, i also have to use Me.Dispatcher.Invoke.
So the result is a little bit complicated, but it works !!

```
            System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
                                  Sub()
                       Me.Dispatcher.Invoke(Sub()
                                                sender.Focus()
                                                sender.SelectAll()
                                            End Sub)
                                  End Sub)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'd just about given up on finding a solution to this. Your answer works (I had to add a bit of casting to make it work with Option Strict On) but I want to make sure I understand why. So what you're saying is, when I click away from the textboxt, it loses focus but whatever I clicked on hasn't gotten it yet. So the textbox loses focus, my sub here gives it back, then what I clicked on gets the focus, and then this fires again because it just lost focus again. The solution seems a bit kludgy, but I can't think of a better way to do it. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, you described well the behaviour. I could not find (for my project) a simpler solution to have both the button clicked AND the focus returning to the first control after.

Answer (score 0):

I would try either moving Focus after SelectAll call or perhaps adding a e.Handled = true statement in there.

Comment: Afraid this doesn't work. Moving Focus after SelectAll had no effect and setting e.Handled to true still makes it loop but prevents the OS from making the cursor stop appearing in the textbox (so I have two textboxes with the cursor)

Comment: Is the value of focus true at the end of function call?

Comment: The value of focus is true if I call textbox_quantity.Focus(), but false if I do not.

Comment: Maybe try adding a handler to focusChanged and see when it is changed back to false.